# How to equip pre-order skins?

Tags: nier-automata

The pre-order edition of the game includes a number of cosmetic items for your pod and yourself as seen [here](http://www.gamestop.com/gs/images/bonus/134318_Day1_bonusLG.jpg).

Are all the cosmetic items automatically given to your character and how would you equip them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Skins are listed as Key Items. Once you've redeemed the preorder codes for the skins, they will appear in your Key Items and you can simply equip them from there.

[image: key items with skins]

From [this guide](http://twinfinite.net/2017/02/nier-automata-how-to-change-your-pod-skin/):

> First off, bring up the game’s main menu and head over to the Items tab. Look for the Key Items option and select that. Here, you’ll find all the important items you’ve picked up over the course of the game. Select the skin that you want to equip, and then hit the Equip option. Once you do this, your Pod will assume the appearance of whatever you picked for it.

Comment: Note for PC Players: You won't need to use any pre-order codes. They'll just be there in your key items section if you bought the game in the pre-order time frame.